# How to fix my Git HEAD after inadvertent branch push?

Tags: git, branch, head, repo, gitgraph.js

I've been a Git user for many moons - in Windows. I used to use CLI+Tortoise Git and rarely encountered problems. I made the switch to Linux (kubuntu 23.10), install VS Code (beauty, btw), and installed the Git Graph extension (truly, wow). Then, while working in a branch, I committed my work and then something happened: it seems my repo now has two heads. I would prefer not to undo the commit in favor of a fix to correct the issue; meanwhile, work continues. The snapshot shows a bit of what my repo looks like and the lines are not connecting back to the root.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOFww.png)

I was trying to commit branch changes locally (only) - but then the 'tool' pushed my changes and created another head? Don't know how to fix this, usually, I commit locally, switch to master, then merge. This is what I thought was going to occur - but the 'tool' outsmarted me.

Tried one of the rebase recommends, results below:

```
djorg@DESKTOP-25485G2 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/6BCF14A3917E5BC71FD48812B8ED0586/MQL4 (master)
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 308.80 KiB | 34.31 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.
To https://github.com/djorgens2/MT4-Master.git
   efa5240..bf6bcee  master -> master

djorg@DESKTOP-25485G2 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/6BCF14A3917E5BC71FD48812B8ED0586/MQL4 (master)
$ git rebase origin master
Current branch master is up to date.

djorg@DESKTOP-25485G2 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/6BCF14A3917E5BC71FD48812B8ED0586/MQL4 (master)
$ git pull origin -r master
From https://github.com/djorgens2/MT4-Master
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

djorg@DESKTOP-25485G2 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/6BCF14A3917E5BC71FD48812B8ED0586/MQL4 (master)
$ git switch man-v5
Switched to a new branch 'man-v5'
branch 'man-v5' set up to track 'origin/man-v5'.

djorg@DESKTOP-25485G2 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/6BCF14A3917E5BC71FD48812B8ED0586/MQL4 (man-v5)
$ git switch master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

djorg@DESKTOP-25485G2 MINGW64 ~/AppData/Roaming/MetaQuotes/Terminal/6BCF14A3917E5BC71FD48812B8ED0586/MQL4 (master)
$
```

Comment: do you still have your `git push` command ? I think you unwillingly pushed to a remote branch named `HEAD`. To confirm whether such a branch exists on your remote: can you run `git ls-remote | grep HEAD` ?

Comment: No, unfortunately the tool executed the command via a series of message box approvals.  I have always preferred to execute cmds from the cli but thought the tool would be less subject to errors.

Comment: ok, what about `git ls-remote | grep HEAD` ?